# what is the range of DateTime.TryParseExact or Convert.ToDateTime() having date format dd/MM/yy

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to know the range of DateTime.TryParseExact method or Convert.ToDateTime() having dd/MM/yy as input format.
like

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/07/05","dd/MM/yy",  new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)
```

or

```
DateTime Time=Convert.ToDateTime("01/07/05");
```

If i will give 01/07/35, it will not know whether I am talking about 1835,1935,2035. So defiantly it has some range. Any body know about its rang with some reference ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're asking how a two digit year is interpreted, it depends on the culture's [TwoDigitYearMax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx) property

Which depends on the computer's settings. To see what the setting is go to:

1. Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options
2. Customize (XP) or Additional Settings (Win7)
3. Date Tab. There is a setting there on how two digit years are interpreted. On my computer it's interpreted as between 1930 and 2029.

Answer (score 4):

Year values from 00 to 29 will give you the years 2000 to 2029, values from 30 to 99 will give you the hears 1930 to 1999.

The value `new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` contains `2029`, which determines the breaking point.

Comment: On your system maybe. It's actually a computer setting.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` range is between `DateTime.MinValue` (**00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001**) to `DateTime.MaxValue` (**23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999**).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx

Default century is controlled by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Think it will assume current [edit] century (not millennium) (set in system clock)

Comment: It doesn't. Also you mean century.