# Can DateTime.ParseExact create 1 year from 01 instead of 2001 with yy?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse a two digit year into a two digit `int` but the following code gives me 2001 instead:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("29NOV01", "ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

var year = date.Year; // .ToString("D4") = 2001 instead of 0001
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? I would prefer not to add another two zeros to the string only to make it work.

Comment: This might be helpful read this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576482/what-is-the-range-of-datetime-tryparseexact-or-convert-todatetime-having-date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The century to be used if there are two digits is contained in the `CultureInfo`:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 100;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("29NOV99", "ddMMMyy", culture);
```

Remember that this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01JAN00", "ddMMMyy", culture);
```

will be parsed as 01 January 0100. Or you could

```
culture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 99;
```

But then the `ParseExact` would throw an exception, because the date 01 January 0000 can't be represented by a `DateTime` (that has a `MinValue` 01 January 0001)

Comment: @SonerGönül 29 Nov 0099, as asked ( `.ToString("D4") = 2001 instead of 0001` )

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I see this method is not very reliable and the answer to my question is _no, it cannot_ because it doesn't work for all values. I think I'd better add the two zeros to the year after all. This way it will always produce the correct result because I cannot guarantee that the year will always be within the range.

Comment: @t3chb0t Is there a problem with my proposed solution?

Answer (score 4):

The `DateTime` structure stores the actual year, not the value that it found when parsing whatever string you provided it.

If you just want the part without the century, why not just do this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("29NOV01", "ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var year = date.Year % 100;
```

or as a string:

```
var year = date.ToString("yy");
```

Comment: I got the impression that the OP literally wants it to parse as the year 1 and not the year 2001.

Comment: I guess that's the net outcome that OP wants to achieve, but I'm willing to wager that OP is not actually parsing two-digit dates from the late Roman period. And presuming that OP wants `0` for dates that end in `00`, my approach will work where the upvoted answer won't.